# How to call a javascript function every second in HTML?

Tags: javascript, countdown

I have multiple paragraphs in an html-file that should show a dynamic countdown.
So I made a Countdown function in javascript, that returns the remaining time every time it is called. Unfortunately, I don't know how to call this function every second in the html file. Can you please help me out?

This is how my html file looks like:
**EDIT, I have many countdown-paragraphs in my html file!**:

```
<p class="countdown"><script>document.write(CountdownAnzeigen('2012-07-16 12:20:00'));</script></p>
<p class="countdown"><script>document.write(CountdownAnzeigen('2012-08-10 10:10:00'));</script></p>
...
```

The javascript function looks like:

```
function CountdownAnzeigen(end_datetime){
    var Now = new Date();
    var Countdown = Date.parse(end_datetime);
    var CountdownText = Countdown.getTime()-Now.getTime();
    return CountdownText;
}
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: @experimentX: Please don't actually pass strings to `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides all answers how to use `setInterval()`, nobody explained, how to get the result into the paragraph. :)

So again, call you function like this:

```
setInterval(function() { CountdownAnzeigen('2012-07-16 12:20:00'); }, 1000);
```

And update the function:

```
// remove return value
return CountdownText;

// and replace it with this
document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = CountdownText;
```

Finally change your HTML to this:

```
<p class="countdown" id="countdown"></p>
```

If you don't use any "onload"-handler, place all your JavaScript below the paragraph and call the function once manually, to have the start time immediately and not the first time after one second.

#### EDIT

If you have multiple paragraphs you could do it like this:

```
<p class="countdown" id="countdown_1"></p>
<p class="countdown" id="countdown_2"></p>

<script>
    setInterval(function() { CountdownAnzeigen('countdown_1', '2012-07-16 12:20:00'); }, 1000)
    setInterval(function() { CountdownAnzeigen('countdown_2', '2012-07-16 12:20:00'); }, 500)
</script>
```

And update the function to:

```
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = a;
```

Where `ìd` is a new parameter from the function call.

Comment: Thank you! But my problem is that I have many countdowns in my html file, all with different timevalues.

Answer (score 1):

```
setInterval(function() {
    CountdownAnzeigen('2012-07-16 12:20:00');
}, 1000);
```

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't work. Now there won't be shown any countdown.

Comment: I tried your solution with document.write and without, but it doesn't work.

Comment: How did you use it? Note that you should avoid `document.write` and instead modify a page by manipulating the DOM.

Comment: @AndiPower You should generally only use `document.write` when creating a new window.  Instead, pick an element and set its `innerHTML` property, like `document.getElementsByClass("countdown")[0].innerHTML = ....`

Comment: @apsillers Because I have many countdown classes, which all have other times I don't want to use this `document.getElementsByClass` method. Is there a way that I can call this function directly within the html paragraph and the function just returns a value? That is my goal.

Answer (score 1):

The `setInterval(foobar, x)` function is used to run a function `foobar` every `x` *milliseconds*.

Note that `foobar` can either be a function to be run *or* a string which will be interpreted as a Javascript, but I believe its accepted that using the string methodology is bad practice.

See the [MDN setInterval docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval).

(See also setInterval's sister method [`setTimeout`'s documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout).)

Comment: Passing a string uses `eval`.  You should never pass a string. :-P

Answer (score 1):

Use `data-` attributes to associate a target time with each element:

```
<p class="countdown" data-target-time="2012-07-06 12:20:00"></p>
<p class="countdown" data-target-time="2012-08-10 10:10:00"></p>
```

Then use a single `setInterval` function to fill each `countdown`-classed element with the result of the countdown function for its related time data:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var countdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("countdown");
    for(var i=0; i < countdowns.length; ++i) {
        var cd = countdowns[i];
        cd.innerHTML = CountdownAnzeigen(cd.getAttribute("data-target-time"));
    }
}, 1000);
```

This creates [completely valid HTML5](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) and still functions correctly in older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can call function periodically also via the [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).

[Example](http://pastebin.com/bwUkq9Q2):

javascript

```
function CountdownAnzeigen(countdown){
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = countdown--;
    if (countdown>0) {
       window.setTimeout(function(){CountdownAnzeigen(countdown);}, 1000);
    } else { alert('The End');}
}
```

html

```
<input type="button" value="count down" onclick="CountdownAnzeigen(10)"/>
<div id="countdown"></div>
```